# Aplicar estilo CSS a una fila de una tabla html dependiendo de un valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tengo una tabla html común, con una columna llamada "estado", cuyos resultados posibles son "si" y "no". y quiero hacer que que todas las filas cuyo estado sea ="no" pintarlas de otro color.

¿Cómo se puede hacer esto con jQuery?

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
  <td>ESTADO</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>DESCRIPCION 1</td>
  <td>SI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>DESCRIPCION 2</td>
  <td>NO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que lleves hasta ahora.

Comment: Como añades los `Resultados posibles` , ya que si llenas la tabla desde lado del servidor, puedes validar esto desde ahí.

Comment: no llevo nada hecho en js, solo la tabla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) puede ser tan breve como:

```js
$("table td:last-child:contains(NO)").parents("tr").css("background-color", "red");
```

Es decir:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("table td:last-child:contains(NO)")
    .parents("tr")
    .css("background-color", "red");
});
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
    <td>ESTADO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>DESCRIPCION 1</td>
    <td>SI</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>DESCRIPCION 2</td>
    <td>NO</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias, funciona!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar la función **`each`** de jQuery para recorrer todos los **`td`** de la tabla, y si éste tiene el valor de **No**, añades al **padre (`tr`) de ese (`td`) una clase**, para que lo entiendas mejor e aquí un ejemplo:

Tenemos la siguiente clase **CSS** que aplicaremos con el script:

```
.no {
  background: red;
}
```

Tenemos la siguiente **tabla**:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Yes/No</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Y con el **siguiente guión usando jQuery** puedes conseguir lo que pretendes:

```
$("td").each(function() {
    var value = this.innerHTML;
    if (/no/i.test(value)) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('no');
    } 
});
```

Como podrás apreciar en el código **he usado una sencilla expresión regular**, esto no es estrictamente necesario, pero si el valor de **no** fuese escrito por el usuario algunos pondrían **NO**, otros **No**, etc.

> Ten en cuenta que esto afectará a todas las tablas, si quieres que
> solo afecte a una determinada tabla con un determinado ID simplemente
> cambias el selector de jQuery así: **`$("#id_tabla td")`**
>
> Y recuerda en añadir la librería de jQuery: **`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`**

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: gracias, pero no me resulta, cambie el id por el de mi tabla mas el nombre de la columna: $("mitabla estado").each(function()

Comment: @daniel2017- Porque en lo que has puesto es imposible que te funcione! En jQuery las id se seleccionan con **`#`** y los tags tal cual son, si la id de tu tabla es **mitabla** te quedaría: **`$("#mitabla td")`**, entiendes?

Comment: @daniel2017- Antes de nada prueba el código tal cual te lo he dado. Y asegúrate de añadir el repositorio de **jQuery** en el **`<head>`** de tu página: **`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`**

Answer (score 2):

Propusieron soluciones con `Jquery` mejores que mi respuesta ,así que propondré una solución, solo con `Javascript`:

```js
const filas = document.getElementById('mitabla').querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
    filas.forEach(function(valor, indice, array){
 if(valor.querySelector('td:last-child').innerText =='no') 
            valor.style.background= '#ccc';
    });
```

```html
<table id="mitabla">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Estado</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Name1</td>
  <td>si</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Name1</td>
  <td>no</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: me da este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Comment: Qué número de columna es, si es la primera es 1 la segunda 3, así le sumas `dos` , aunque la mejor respuesta es la expuesta  por Javi.

Comment: si, era error mi con el numero de columna. Funciona pero solo marca la primera fila

Comment: @daniel2017- Debes primero entender bien como funcionan los **selectores de jQuery**, si no, ninguna respuesta te va a servir de ayuda!... Léete esta guía sobre selectores: **https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp**